# Xcode: How to add arrays in InfoPlist.strings

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, plist

I have a localized `InfoPlist.strings` file with key value pairs like this:

```
NSHealthShareUsageDescription     = "This enables you to sync your workout data and measurements with Apple Health.";
NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription    = "This enables you to sync your workout data and measurements with Apple Health.";
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription    = "This enables you to add photos from your library.";
NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription = "This enables you to add photos from your library.";
```

Now I want to add `CFBundleLocalizations`, which requires an array. If I do...

```
CFBundleLocalizations = ["en", "de"];
```

...I get the build error "validation failed: Couldn't parse property list because the input data was in an invalid format".

I guess it's because that's not how you write an array in a `.strings` file. How do I do it correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Localizing non-root InfoPlist values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58086944/localizing-non-root-infoplist-values)

Comment: Unfortunately not, since they just explain how to add localized strings, which I'm already doing and which works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you should localize these items in your property list at all...

But if I remember correctly you simply need to introduce custom keys in your original plist and then present a translation for each item in array. So an array in your plist looks like this:

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>de</string>
</array>
```

(To see this right-click your plist and select "open as -> source code")

You should change it to for instance:

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>LOCALIZATION_KEY_EN</string>
    <string>LOCALIZATION_KEY_DE</string>
</array>
```

then in `.string` use these keys as:

```
LOCALIZATION_KEY_EN = "en";
LOCALIZATION_KEY_DE = "de";
```

Comment: It's just to simplify my workflow. Sometimes I have to start my project from scratch and then I need to manually copy in my .plist values. If I could set the localizations array in the localized .strings file, I just need to update two files, the DE and the EN versions. Otherwise, I also have to update the base file. Your solution, unfortunately, also requires me to update 3 files